# Why doesn't the HTML within the <ul> tag not show up in this jsfiddle

Tags: html, css

I am messing around with this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5LXc/2/

I am trying to place the search form on the very right side of the black bar, but it isn't rendering right, and for some reason the options withing the `<ul>` tag are also not showing up.

Any idea why the dropdown that is inside the `<ul>` tag isn't rendering at all?

Thanks!!

Comment: use float:left, float:right
and on the parent div clear:both

Comment: `<input type="submit"  value="Search"></input>`?

Comment: @dotweb `<input>` has only one tag ==> `<input type="submit" value="Search" />`!

Comment: @ComFreek LOL, exactly. But the autor of this question used the code I quoted above, obviously.

Comment: Sorry I am not following - I got rid of the </input> a while ago - maybe we are not seeing the same versions of the code there? How do I make you see the latest?

Comment: It's really unclear what you want. I see no less than 3 search forms in your fiddle, including one on the very right.

Comment: @GeekedOut jsfiddle.net/id/version so simply /2 for the version 2.

Comment: @dotweb I see - you guys weren't seeing my changes. But when I did something like /3/ it didn't work.  And /2/ reset my changes :(

Comment: @GeekedOut Press `Update` @dotweb Ah okay ;)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on your code. Here's what I think you were going for: http://cssdesk.com/pcWfx

Avoid relative/absolute positioning whenever possible. [Save it for items that should appear on "top" of the rest of the page.] You usually don't need it. I used it here only to create the drop-down menus.

Much cleaner HTML:

```
<div id="nav">      
  <form name="form" method="post" id="header_search">
    <label for="query">Search</label>
    <input type="text" size="10" name="query" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
  </form> 
  <ul>         
    <li>
      <a href="link">Menu item</a>
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="link">Some item</a></li> 
        <li><a href="link">Some item</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="link">Menu item 2</a>
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="link">Some item</a></li> 
        <li><a href="link">Some item</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Much more straightforward CSS:

```
/* the navbar */
#nav {
  background-image: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/brownbannerbar.png');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;    
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px; /* vertically-center text */
}

#nav form {
  float: right; /* put form on the right */
}

/* first-level nav links */
#nav ul li {
  float: left; /* line up side-by-side on left */
  position: relative; /* position dropdown relative to this */
}

/* first-level hover color */
#nav ul li:hover {
  background: #666; 
}

/* second level nav links */
#nav ul li ul {
  display: none; /* hide initially */
  line-height: 1.4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
}

#nav ul li ul li {
  background: #666;
  padding: 0; 
  width: 100%;
}

/* show second level links on first-level hover */
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block; 
}

/* second-level hover color */
#nav ul li ul li:hover{
  background: #999;  
}

/* remove margins/paddings/bullets */
#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* style links */
#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: and if you must have your border-radius:

`#nav ul li ul li:last-child { border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 5px; }`